# I need to write a function which returns the compliment of A(supplied) with respect to U(universal set also entered by user)

Tags: haskell

I don't believe I am allowed to use any non standard libraries.

I've tried messing about with indenting like tabs and spaces, however I am a Haskell novice so it is very likely I have missed something.

```
subset :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
subset [] ys = True
subset (x:xs) ys
 elem x ys = subset xs ys
 let otherwise = False

complement :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Maybe [a]
 complement [] ys = Just ys
 complement xs ys
  subset xs ys = Just (filter (not.(`elem`xs))ys)
      otherwise = Nothing
```

Expected result with entered data([1,2,3] [1..5]) = Just [4,5]

Comment: @chepner, it seems unfortunate to mark *this one* a dupe. It's far better than the other versions I've seen. Can we reshuffle the dupe graph edges?

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you are trying to write a pattern guard, but left out the `|`.  Try:

```hs
complement :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Maybe [a]
complement [] ys = Just ys
complement xs ys
  | subset xs ys = Just (filter (not.(`elem`xs))ys)
  | otherwise = Nothing
```

There are similar issues in `subset`.  There are a couple other indentation issues, though maybe those were introduced pasting into SO.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer, although I'm still getting an error:

    parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)
   |
20 | complement :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Maybe [a]    | ^

Comment: Maybe you still have errors in the guard in `subset`, or the 3 lines of `complement` don't begin in the first column.